# Manhwa: female main character with the power to grow plants becomes her family's heir

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga

I believe it is a Korean novel/manhwa. The main character is female and lives in "medieval" world.  She is the daughter of nobles and learns magic from a famous magician along with 2 boys, one of whom is from a knight's family.  I don't remember if she reincarnated or not.

She has a possibly unique magic power that allows her to grow plants, which I believe she uses to make potions. After time skip her parents die in an "accident", and her brother, the heir, leaves the house secretly because of debt. The main character meets a duke (maybe) that gives her money in exchange for her magic power to make tree/plants in a desert.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall any details of the appearance of the characters, or any notable details of the setting or art style?

Comment: @DavidW I believe in 2019-20. Teacher (male) had white long hair. Duke had tan/olive/darkish skin tone and was very wealthy/wealthiest of nobles. Overall they had fair? skin tone. Medieval setting with magic as it is common with reincarnation stories so possible it is the case with this one as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *[The Garden of Red Flowers](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-garden-of-red-flowers)*.

> Venianne was living her life peacefully until she was reincarnated in her friend's novel as a supporting character. Luckily, she knew the story well and was happy to have stumbled upon a character with the future all mapped out. Why bother to go back to your old life when you can take it easy in a mansion? Except that her destiny did not seem all mapped out as she hoped... What if the storyline could be changed?

The protagonist learns magic alongside two boys; she has low mana but a specialty towards growing magical plants. The teacher has long white hair.

[image: Growing plants with teacher]

After her parents die, she makes a deal with the duke to cultivate a "tree of prosperity" in exchange for dealing with her debt. This is something that normally takes over a thousand years but she's capable of doing it comparatively quickly, which would help his vast but unproductive land.

[image: Desert transformation plan]

A better picture of the Duke, who is as described:

[image: The wealthy Duke]

Comment: I'll try to find some screenshots. I'm positive this is the story, but it's been a while so I'm a bit hazy on the details, and the stuff needed isn't conveniently in the first chapter.

Comment: Thank you! This is the one.